# How to set ListBox.ItemsPanel in code not in xaml?

Tags: silverlight

I create a ListBox in C# code (in a converter I decide that which control must shown). Unfortunately I couldn't set ItemsPanel to a WrapPanel in C# code. Currently I have a code like this (as workaround):

In xaml file (ResourceDictionary):

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="HorizontalWrapPanelItemsPanelTemplate" >
    <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

And in C# file (Converter):

```
listBox.ItemsPanel = Application.Current.Resources["HorizontalWrapPanelItemsPanelTemplate"] as ItemsPanelTemplate;
```

It work correctly, but I will have a code like this:

```
listBoxEdit.ItemsPanel = new WrapPanel();   //Not Work
```

Or

```
WrapPanel wrapPanel = new WrapPanel();
listBoxEdit.ItemsPanel = new ItemsPanelTemplate(wrapPanel);   //Not Work
```

Is it possible that I have a code like this? Or is exist a better code from currently my workaround?

tanx :)

Answer (score 4):

In WPF you would be using the FrameworkElementFactory :

```
FrameworkElementFactory factoryPanel = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(WrapPanel));
factoryPanel.SetValue(WrapPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);

ItemsPanelTemplate template = new ItemsPanelTemplate();
template.VisualTree = factoryPanel;

menu.ItemsPanel = template;
```

In Silverlight this will not work, you will have to use XAMLReader :

```
listBoxEdit.ItemsPanel = (ItemsPanelTemplate)XamlReader.Load(@"<ItemsPanelTemplate xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' >
    <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>");
```

From : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scmorris/archive/2008/04/14/defining-silverlight-datagrid-columns-at-runtime.aspx

Comment: OK thanks, but i think my code is more clean and beauty from this. :D